# app.config not compatible when service reference change

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services

I get warnings regarding my app.config file in my project because I upgraded my service reference to a newer version with some different methods and configurations. Is there a way that I can generate a new app.config file and not have to change all its bindings and endpoints because that will be very exhausting. there must be a way i guess.

This is my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <!-- This section defines the logging configuration for My.Application.Log -->
            <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="FileLog"/>
                    <!-- Uncomment the below section to write to the Application Event Log -->
                    <!--<add name="EventLog"/>-->
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <switches>
            <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
        </switches>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add name="FileLog"
                 type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
                 initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
            <!-- Uncomment the below section and replace APPLICATION_NAME with the name of your application to write to the Application Event Log -->
            <!--<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="APPLICATION_NAME"/> -->
        </sharedListeners>
    </system.diagnostics>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="Apsis Newsletter Pro v3 APISoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="Apsis Newsletter Pro v3 APISoap12">
                    <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                        messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    </textMessageEncoding>
                    <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                        maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                        keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                        realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                        useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://api.anpdm.com/ExternalAPIService.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Apsis Newsletter Pro v3 APISoap"
                contract="Apsis5.ApsisNewsletterProv3APISoap" name="Apsis Newsletter Pro v3 APISoap" />
            <endpoint address="http://api.anpdm.com/ExternalAPIService.asmx"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="Apsis Newsletter Pro v3 APISoap12"
                contract="Apsis5.ApsisNewsletterProv3APISoap" name="Apsis Newsletter Pro v3 APISoap12" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

These are the warnings:

**Warning   1**:Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Referenced type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array' is only valid for encoded SOAP.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://api.anpdm.com/']/wsdl:portType[@name='Apsis_x0020_Newsletter_x0020_Pro_x0020_v3_x0020_APIHttpGet']   C:\Users\Pedram\Desktop\Apsis5 (Avanza)\Apsis5\Service References\Apsis5\Reference.svcmap   1   1   Apsis5

**Warning   2** Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://api.anpdm.com/']/wsdl:portType[@name='Apsis_x0020_Newsletter_x0020_Pro_x0020_v3_x0020_APIHttpGet']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://api.anpdm.com/']/wsdl:binding[@name='Apsis_x0020_Newsletter_x0020_Pro_x0020_v3_x0020_APIHttpGet']    C:\Users\Pedram\Desktop\Apsis5 (Avanza)\Apsis5\Service References\Apsis5\Reference.svcmap   1   1   Apsis5

**Warning   3** Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://api.anpdm.com/']/wsdl:binding[@name='Apsis_x0020_Newsletter_x0020_Pro_x0020_v3_x0020_APIHttpGet']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://api.anpdm.com/']/wsdl:service[@name='Apsis_x0020_Newsletter_x0020_Pro_x0020_v3_x0020_API']/wsdl:port[@name='Apsis_x0020_Newsletter_x0020_Pro_x0020_v3_x0020_APIHttpGet'] C:\Users\Pedram\Desktop\Apsis5 (Avanza)\Apsis5\Service References\Apsis5\Reference.svcmap   1   1   Apsis5

**Warning   4** Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Referenced type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array' is only valid for encoded SOAP.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://api.anpdm.com/']/wsdl:portType[@name='Apsis_x0020_Newsletter_x0020_Pro_x0020_v3_x0020_APIHttpPost']  C:\Users\Pedram\Desktop\Apsis5 (Avanza)\Apsis5\Service References\Apsis5\Reference.svcmap   1   1   Apsis5

**Warning   5** Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://api.anpdm.com/']/wsdl:portType[@name='Apsis_x0020_Newsletter_x0020_Pro_x0020_v3_x0020_APIHttpPost']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://api.anpdm.com/']/wsdl:binding[@name='Apsis_x0020_Newsletter_x0020_Pro_x0020_v3_x0020_APIHttpPost']   C:\Users\Pedram\Desktop\Apsis5 (Avanza)\Apsis5\Service References\Apsis5\Reference.svcmap   1   1   Apsis5

**Warning   6** Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://api.anpdm.com/']/wsdl:binding[@name='Apsis_x0020_Newsletter_x0020_Pro_x0020_v3_x0020_APIHttpPost']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://api.anpdm.com/']/wsdl:service[@name='Apsis_x0020_Newsletter_x0020_Pro_x0020_v3_x0020_API']/wsdl:port[@name='Apsis_x0020_Newsletter_x0020_Pro_x0020_v3_x0020_APIHttpPost']    C:\Users\Pedram\Desktop\Apsis5 (Avanza)\Apsis5\Service References\Apsis5\Reference.svcmap   1   1   Apsis5

Comment: What are the warnings? Updating service reference should change the app.config.

Comment: this is one of them: Warning 1 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Referenced type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array' is only valid for encoded SOAP.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://api.anpdm.com/']/wsdl:portType[@name='Apsis_x0020_Newsletter_x0020_Pro_x0020_v3_x0020_APIHttpGet'] C:\Users\Pedram\Desktop\Apsis5 (Avanza)\Apsis5\Service References\Apsis5\Reference.svcmap 1 1 Apsis5

Comment: Please add it and the app.config to your question

Comment: Done. added app.config and the warnings.

Comment: Looks like there is no problem with your app.config but with the service wsdl content

Comment: When I run the program, it gives me an InvalidOperationException saying could not find endpoint element with the name "Apsis Newsletter prov..." This might be because no configuration files were found for your application or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.

Comment: Is the app.config belongs to the main project or a dll? You have to add the config to the main project, or look here in my post http://linqto.net/blog/2012/08/keep-wcf-client-configuration-in-a-class-library-app-condig/

Comment: no dll is involved with this i suppose.i deleted the app.config file and deleted the service and added the reference again. but i get the same error. the web service has done some modifications on their methods. it used to work before with the same code but i need to use the new methods with my code.

Comment: so you think the problem is from the service side?

Comment: Try to start all over with a new project. If it doesn't work then maybe this is the server issue

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the root problem with this but I tried to add my service as a web reference and everything started working.